# Automatically update php array every morning

Tags: php, arrays, excel, automation, download

I am grabbing live auction data from a feed, then saving them in an array and also downloading them as an excel file (i need them both). Now, for another part of my project, I need to do this (collect the data from feed and download it as exc file) every morning at 9 am.

How can I achieve this? Honestly, I am new to this...so you might have to explain your solution little bit more thoroughly to me, sorry! And thank you all for your time and help!!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: You need an scheduled task, if you are on a hosting chances are you can use a cron. If by anychance you can't use a cron, then it depends on what your platform offers you to create scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to make use of [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_%28Unix%29) if you are using a Unix server or Windows Task Scheduler in the case of windows.

Like this you will be able to use programmed tasks.

For windows here's a tutorial apported by @Chris Cooney:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-windows-programs-on-a-schedule/

In the case of using cron you could do it easily like this:

```
00 09 * *  php -f your_relative_or_full_path_URL/params > /dev/null
```

9 in the morning every day for the previous example.

Comment: Perhaps adding [this tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-windows-programs-on-a-schedule/) to your answer might be useful to OP.

Comment: Thank you Steve and Chris. Let me go through the tutorial and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: oh gosh...i forgot to mention that it's a PHP file. Looks like now i have to convert the php file to an executable file first :/

Comment: You don't need to convert any php script to an executable if you have php installed

Comment: The only executable you need is the php binary, to be able to run it from the command line